# Write a Unicode scribal character in an HTML page (with Junicode)?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding, fonts, webfonts

This is hopefully a very simple question, but one a lot of Googling has not found the answer to!

I would like to display a Unicode character from the Latin Extended-D set on a web page ([PDF description of Extended-D](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA720.pdf)), using [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/), which supports Extended-D.

The code I would like to display is "A760 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER VY".

This is my page in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Font Experiments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body id="home">
    &#8166;
    &#A760;
</body></html>
```

And this is what my stylesheet looks like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Junicode';
    src: url('../fonts/junicode-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/junicode-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Junicode.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Junicode.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/junicode-regular-webfont.svg#JunicodeRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
     font-family: junicode, gentium, caslon roman, serif; 
}
```

I have checked and Junicode is being loaded correctly. But while the first Unicode character displays correctly as ῦ, for the second character I just see a literal `&#A760` on the page.

How can I indicate that this should be displayed as Unicode Extended-D character A760?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change to hexadecimal:

```
&#xA760;
```

Comment: Thanks! that was the missing step.